# ionic+firebase+elasticsearch can't auth with elasticsearch.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, elasticsearch, ionic-framework

```
const client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: [
    {
      host: '35.192.45.130//elasticsearch',
      auth: 'user:password',
      protocol: 'http',
      port: 80
    }
  ]
});
//

await client.ping({
  // ping usually has a 3000ms timeout
  requestTimeout: 1000
}, function (error) {
  if (error) {
    console.trace('elasticsearch cluster is down!');
  } else {
    console.log('All is well');
  }
});
```

I can't authorize to elasticsearch with ionic. But with Postman i already can login and do some actions.

Error is

*Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.*

Comment: check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: 1) try to install cors plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors/dboaklophljenpcjkbbibpkbpbobnbld?hl=en and enable it, then try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to enable **CORS** in a browser using [this plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors/dboaklophljenpcjkbbibpkbpbobnbld?hl=en) in chrome browser.

More about CORS [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)